# Верно ли утверждение, что в JavaScript невозможно создать автономную копию произвольного объекта?

Tags: javascript

О глубоком копировании объектов в JavaScript обсуждений довольно много, и на англоязычном StackOverflow предлагается множество вариантов решений. У меня даже есть [свой собственный](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABAEwKaoA4BsCeBhLBVAeQCMArVaASUixGRjAHMBBAJ3YEMcBnPLr1QAeAKJ4AsqwDKEdjAxQylaIlQAPKKjDJeiOBSpQAfAAoAUIiuIoXds1RLD0Yuw7ccALkTips%20YrKRuYAlN6%20MnIKTipQiADe5paIMMCIpgCEMLwAcgg5IFhYQdCmtvaOJUpunDwhIQnJ1jYAFuxwAO6IYKhdopxw7KYARAAqLaiIdswgALbacS2CNjgYkwDkBrHriKQgcTAHemCFWMMhANzJAL5JVqnp7jwAdNlPOGXTlc7V7-WNzXYjhA7CQaEwuAIRHenwqMSMrj%20VystysQKgILB6Gw%20EIPTyYHeVVhDnhLhqHku5luSVAkFgCBQ2MheNQBKJPzEkkiATJJhJ31i4W5-miVTCPhFUUCPwBiAgCF4cS2RihPQA6oMANYYGBUVDeeKIADaGHaa3YUBwOS4828SvkLAAut5wFqwJ0wBdENdEABeBLXZGIYCDdIKsBKk2IM1wC1Wm3zAA0MfNqEtOAAalx6JMnfo0lVngt5KheAK%20f9Es0HqZsgVZqR06ZY-GszmQKgGgAfbspXjSKCO5gttMZ7O5nt97IAITgcCwqC4YFHcfTVonnanqbX447kz9h%206pwa1ea%20h%20atQmvYOr1EFQprHCdtqHzAdb6-bueDzQjsBOVBfx9JoUjSUx3leXgYU-PdJ1PUCrBVaArxvO99SfXcX3md8mQhXFoVqD5YI3fcqXPeUEAAztgNRaxa3rfJTmJEjvy3BCKOQqBUO1XUMNYxM339PCcSvdkiJY582K7WibmSdFMQvWIeNvPiHymPQ3Q9DokGWCJRRlWIrhpOloHgLF8Kvd4uT8aU%20TMcpSXebxrK0z1jAlfS7KqOUIyjCBWXeNC1INRBXLAd13OE40nWDUN2HDRU4mNFIdA0FM7A8URF3mMA4nzOA0kcxxIJLPVyyrUDa0Q-sGybIZMp4bLUFyqApxq7JB2HUxGpwZrWvaijZ3nRdlx6oj%20oWQbz2yABVNLgCYVBkHGrKcqmxBexq3rJry-0jxOIpQI488AsIjxgvvR8mDQdRcJ29a8uAqx-yYGjQLo%205wMgt4iNWprHrak6-0CojLowm6NFw8FRNBjx-r6wHyNOqi3qAj6qvAxiwAKIpiQelqpuB6wzp6ILeKu41Ibu4SYZZIhxI8fGJqR2SUXk4FQXlOGeHB9TljcnSNMlWzeSqYyknMUyGSQbHceKH4WzgLQ8pgHMqldCLtLACUMGVhY1YV2J%20yUow5QUrmrTWQqY311X1dlQ8A2GLjhkQAAyd3bZV2AHeNjIDtOCWpfAMzGXrOZ6qVn3Dbq9NNcinTdbt32sDjhLsmPRt03NzmkCt1Abb1mOc3T-bnZObP2GGYPpfM-suqYEdi4NnNG5YBPteTkusHb5gTYdJvc4xS3VkLtIW-t3uhyHp3EGGQeWBr6laVDmX%20znBclxXSfU830awE3ULBZ17xd8N-ft6Pk3SBG7fh8Ugui5Ti%207%20Xa%205%20GW%20t%20XZeTLX%20uc0FpLRWsVKAR9O6eglGA6%20mdwBoEWj0ZAD9R7WyKl8cB%205y7z3gagRBy0-7mCAA).

Но перед тем, как браться за эту задачу снова, я хотел бы задаться вопросом - а возможно ли в принципе *автономно* клонировать *произвольный* объект? Многие решения (в том числе последняя версия моего) не учитывают:

- Свойства со значениями типа "функция"
- Геттеры и сеттеры
- Неперечисляемые свойства
- Map-ы и Set-ы (не говоря уж о WeakMap и WeakSet)

Я знаю, что это сообщение читают не только профессионалы, но и новички, не понимающие глубины проблемы, а оттого может возникнуть соблазн ответить что-то вроде: "Ха! Да всё ж элементарно! `const clone = { ...original }` - и всё!!!". Но если бы всё было так просто, я бы не задавал этот вопрос на седьмом году в веб-разработке, а потому разберём и отсеем популярные ложные решения.

Но сначала уточним определения.
**Глубокое копирование объекта** подразумевает, что изменение *любых* свойств клонированного объекта, **включая свойства всех его дочерних объектов**, никак не повлияет на исходный экземпляр, при этом клонированный объект полностью идентичен исходному экземпляру, включая функции-свойства, неперичисляемые свойства и так далее.

### Разбор и отсев неверных решений

#### Сериализация с последующей десериализацией

В этом методе мы сначала сериализуем объект с помощью `JSON.stringify(original)`, а потом десериализуем его с помощью `JSON.parse`. В одну строчку это будет так:

```js
JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original))
```

Попробуем клонировать нижеследующий объект **original**:

```js
const original = {
    alpha: "FOO",
  bravo: () => { return "BAR" }
}

const clone = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(original));
```

Но если мы это выведем это в консоль, то свойство **bravo** будет утрачено.
Дальше этот метод нам уже неинтересен.

#### Object.assign и Spread Operator

Синтаксис вида

```js
const clone = { ...original }
```

или

```js
const clone = Object.assign({}, original )
```

глубокого клонирования не делает - по сути это замена одного контейнера на другой, а содержимое ссылается на ту же область памяти, что и в исходном объекте.

```js
const original = {
    alpha: "FOO",
  bravo: {
    charlie: "BAR"
  }
}

const clone = { ...original };
clone.bravo.charlie = "HOGE";

console.log(original.bravo.charlie); // "HOGE"!!! Какого ... ?!
```

Тоже самое и насчёт частного случая объекта - массива:

```js
const clone = [ ...original ];
```

Ну а копировать каждый дочерний объект по отдельности, как это Дан Абрамов предлагал в своём Redux-е - это
какая-то дикость для третьего десятилетия 21-го века - о каких нанотехнологиях, робототехнике и терраформировании Марса можно говорить, когда мне предлагают заниматься такой рутинной работой? Вот так вот эта рутинная ерунда выглядела:

```js
function updateVeryNestedField(state, action) {
  return {
    ...state,
    first: {
      ...state.first,
      second: {
        ...state.first.second,
        [action.someId]: {
          ...state.first.second[action.someId],
          fourth: action.someValue
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

### Проблемы с глубоким копированием произвольных объектов

#### Копирование функций

Во-первых, непонятно что вообще подразумевает **глубокое клонирование функции**.
Технически, наверное, это означает декларирование той же функции, что и уже существующая, но в другой области памяти. Но возможно, я что-то не учитываю.

Я начинал карьеру сразу с синтаксиса ES6, поэтому не застал тех времён, когда программисты забивали гвозди тапками, используя функции в качестве классов. Если подобные фокусы в расчёт не брать, то

```
function original() {

}

const clone = original;
```

хотя и не будет глубоким копированием, но может ли оно причинить какие-либо проблемы?

На англоязычном StackOverflow нашел [такое решение](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6772648/4818123):

```
const newFunc = oldFunc.bind({});
```

Если такое решение не вызовет никаких сторонних эффектов, то возьму его на заметку.

Так или иначе, здесь мы говорим о глубоком клонировании объектов, в частности свойств-функций (методов). Там внутри методов может быть ещё и `this`, и нужно чтобы при глубоком копировании ссылка была на `this` клона.

#### Копирование геттеров и сеттеров

При переборе через `Object.entries(original)` (как в моём выше приведённом решении) и для геттеров, и для сеттеров значениями будут те значения, которые эти геттеры и сеттеры возвращают (а поскольку сеттеры по своей природе ничего не возвращают, то это будет `undefined`):

```js
const original = {
  alpha: "FOO",
  get charle() {
    return this.alpha + "__" + "BAR";
  },
  set delta(value) {
    this.alpha = value;
  }
}

for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(original)) {
  console.log(key);
  console.log(value);
}
```

Значением свойства `charle` здесь будет строка `FOO__BAR`.

```
alpha
FOO
charle
FOO__BAR
delta
undefined
```

Не получится и так (будет тот же результат):

```
for (const key of Object.keys(original)) {
  // ...
}
```

#### Неперичисляемые свойства

Сказать по правде, за весь свой опыт мне почти никогда не приходилось итерировать неперичисляемые свойства. Но в принципе, узнать о существовании неперичислямых свойств мы можем *(например, через `Object.getOwnPropertyNames(object1)`) и тем более обратиться к ним, а потому дальше - все проблемы, что и выше.

#### Map-ы и Set-ы

Map не может быть конвертирована в JSON, и возможно это вызовет проблемы (не уверен, что предложенное ранее мной решение может быть доработано путём улучшения; возможно придётся в корне сменить подход).

Возможно, эти коллекции будут нуждаться в отдельной обработке путём создания нового контейнера такого же типа. Но ведь со временем в ES6 будут добавляться новые контейнеры, и тогда придётся вносить изменения в реализацию

### Итоговый вопрос

А вопрос такой: все приведённые выше проблемы с глубоким клонированием производных объектов плюс те, которые я не назвал - в принципе преодолимы? Это можно учесть при создании функции глубокого копирования? Или реалистично автономно копировать лишь объекты, включающие в себя только те типы данных, которые могут быть сериализованы в JSON (number, string, boolean, null, Array, object)?

Comment: Неужели это нельзя ёмко сформулировать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создать полностью независимый объект в общем случае невозможно.

Из нового - приватные свойства, которые никак нельзя ни прочитать, ни перенести:

```js
class Smth {
  get #x() { return Math.random() }
  get x() { return this.#x }
}

var obj = new Smth()

console.log(obj.x)
console.log(obj.x)
console.log(obj.x)
```

Из старого - все замыкания:

```js
var obj = (function () {
  var x = 0
  
  return {
    doSmth() {
      return ++x
    }
  }
})()

console.log(obj.doSmth())
console.log(obj.doSmth())
console.log(obj.doSmth())
```

И никакие копирования прототипов, getter'ов привязывания функций и всё остальное не поможет.

Comment: Также из старого - в общем случае нельзя создать копию exotic object.

Comment: также с клонированием html-элементов и обработчиков событий тоже не все очевидно

Comment: @PavelMayorov, так exotic object можно определять и создавать аналогичный?

Comment: @Grundy, dom-элементы клонироваться умеют. С событиями - да, вроде проблемы.

Comment: @Qwertiy, без событий - не будет полное копирование :-) ну и для канваса вообще беда, похоже, потому что нарисованное не копируется

Comment: @Qwertiy ну и как вы создадите копию для proxy, bound function, объекта arguments, или для immutable prototype object, который в принципе нельзя создать напрямую?

Comment: @PavelMayorov, для прокси - вероятно, никак (из него же нельзя достать ни объект, ни хэндлеры). Bound function идёт лесом вместе с обычным function с замыканием, о котором написано у меня в ответе. А вот arguments - вроде легко: `(function () { return arguments }).apply(null, arguments)` (ну и перед apply ещё склонировать внутренности). Object prototype вообще не вижу причин копировать.

Comment: Дорогие друзья, благодарю Вас всех за ответы и комментарии! Совместными усилиями, мы исчерпали тему глубокого копирования объектов в ECMAScript.